# Converting hourly to daily data for multiple locations

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am converting hourly to daily data for multiple locations using this code. I want to combine the data by location and also by date.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

StartDateTime <- dmy_hm("01-01-1981 00:00")
EndDateTime <- dmy_hm("31-01-1981 23:00")

date_hour_seq <- seq.POSIXt(StartDateTime, EndDateTime, by = "hour")

DF2 <- data.frame(df, DateTime = date_hour_seq,
Mintemp = rnorm(length(date_hour_seq), 300))

DF3 <- DF2 %\>% group_by(date = date(time)) %\>%
summarise(Mintemp = mean(Mintemp),
Maxtemp = mean(Maxtemp))
```

Comment: I may not be following, but if you just need two levels of grouping try mutate(date = date(time) %>% group_by(date, location). Group_by is for specifying groups, you can have as many layers as needed.

Comment: To get better, faster help, it may be best to parse this down to the *minimal* code needed to create the issue